# Find children of a certain type

Tags: javascript

I have an array of all the `forms` in my page. I want to iterate through all the forms, and find the buttons in them. How can I achieve this in **Javascript alone, without any libraries?**

Here's my JS code :

```
var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');

for(var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++;){
    var form = forms[i];
    form.addEventListener('submit', validateForm);
}

function validateForm(e){
    e.preventDefault();    
    var button = ?; // I want to get the button that is a child of this form
}
```

I know that I can use this to get all the buttons that are children of a form :

```
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('form button');
```

But how can I get just one button that is a  children of **this** form?

I've seen this question asked multiple times, but it was always to find the children of a parent that was known, with a specific `id` or something like that. I have no idea how many forms there will be in the page, and I have no control on wether or not they have unique `id` or anything else that could be used to differentiate them when using `querySelectorAll()`.

Is it possible to achieve what I want?

I'm looking for the pure JS alternative to this in jQuery :

```
var $form = $('form');
var $childButton = $form.find('button');
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Element has equivalent versions of [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector)/[All](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) and so can be called from elements as well as document. So if you are looking for a button inside a form element you can just call querySelector from the form element

```
var form = document.querySelector("#SomeForm");
//Will find the first button in the form
var someBtn = form.querySelector("button");
//Will find all buttons in the form.
var someBtns = form.querySelectorAll("button");
```

Demo

```js
let forms = document.querySelectorAll("form");
[].forEach.call(forms,form=>{
   form.querySelector("button").innerText += " - Modified";
});
```

```html
<form>
  <button>A button</button><br>
  <input><input>
</form>
<form><br><br>
  <button>B button</button><br>
  <input><input><br>
  <button>C button</button>
</form><br><br>
<form>
  <button>D button</button><br>
  <input><input>
</form>
```

Comment: That was so simple, I can't believe I didn't try this or found this before .. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select the first `button` descendant, you can use `querySelector`.

But if you want to make sure it's a child, then you can use `[].find`:

```
[].find.call(form.children, function(child) {
  return child.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'button';
});
```

Alternatively, some browsers support the `:scope` psudo-class:

```
form.querySelector(":scope > button");
```

Hopefully it won't be removed together with scoped stylesheets and `@scope` at-rule.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't really clear. There is a *document.forms* collection that is all the forms in a document in DOM order, so:

```
var firstForm = document.forms[0];
```

will get the first form. If your buttons have names, you can get the button with  name "Fred" in the first form using:

```
var fred = document.forms[0].Fred;
```

Or the first button in the first form with:

```
var firstButton = document.forms[0].querySelector('button');
```

Or all the buttons in the first form with:

```
var firstButton = document.forms[0].querySelectorAll('button');
```

and so on. Note that form controls can be associated with a form using the *form* attribute, but not be inside the form. E.g.

```
<form id="foo">
  <!--  stuff in the form -->
</form>
<button type="submit" for="foo">Submit the form</button>
```

In this case the *querySelector* syntax fails but form property access doesn't, so you might need to loop over the form's *elements* collection:

```
for var i=0, firstButton; i<firstForm.elements.length; i++) {
  if (firstForm.elements[i].tagName.toLowerCase() == 'button') {
    // This is the first button associated with the form, 
    // even if not actually in the form
  }
}
```

So if you want to cover *every* case, your code needs to be very generic. But if you narrow down the likely scenarios, the code is very much simpler.